# Use Gershgorin's theorem to show that a matrix is nonsingular

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, numerical-linear-algebra

Given two matrices $$A = \begin{pmatrix}
    3 & -\frac{1}{2} & 0 \\
    -\frac{1}{2} & 1 & -\frac{1}{2} \\
    0 & -\frac{1}{2} & 1 \\
    \end{pmatrix}, \qquad D = \begin{pmatrix}
    \alpha & 0 & 0 \\
    0 & 1 & 0 \\
    0 & 0 & 1 \\
    \end{pmatrix}, \quad\alpha \neq 0$$

I'm first asked to bound the eigenvalues of $\mathrm{A}$. And then using the fact that $\mathrm{D^{-1}AD}$ has the same eigenvalues as A finding a better bound for the eigenvalues of $\mathrm{A}$. I did this also with applying Gershgorin's theorem on $\mathrm{D^{-1}AD}$. Finally I'm asked to conclude that $\mathrm{A}$ is nonsingular.

I don't know why I can conclude that $\mathrm{A}$ is nonsingular after applying Gershgorin's theorem on $\mathrm{D^{-1}AD}$. I know that a strictly diagonally dominant matrix is nonsingular and positive definite, but this is not the case for $\mathrm{A}$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint:** Define
$$
A(\alpha) = [D(\alpha)]^{-1}AD(\alpha) = \pmatrix{3 & -1/2\alpha & 0\\-\alpha/2 & 1 & -1/2\\0 & -1/2 & 1}
$$
Find a value of $\alpha$ for which $A(\alpha)$ is diagonally dominant.

Comment: But if I find such a value why should this mean that A is strictly diagonally dominant? Because A is still the same matrix..

Comment: But $A$ has the same eigenvalues as $A(\alpha)$

Comment: So if two matrices have the same eigenvalues and one is strictly diagonally dominant the other must be also strictly diagonally dominant?

Comment: No.  But if two matrices have the same eigenvalues and one is invertible, then the other must also be invertible.